# What is [A] in Scala?

Tags: scala

I've seen `[A]` in [playframework site](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition). I found that `[T]` means **any type**, `[S]` is for **sub type**. But I couldn't find what is for `[A]`. Interestingly, it's used right after function name(`logging`).

```
import play.api.mvc._

def logging[A](action: Action[A])= Action.async(action.parser) { request =>
  Logger.info("Calling action")
  action(request)
}
```

So, what does `[A]` mean in Scala?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354803/scala-type-parameter-bracket

Comment: Like `<T>` in Java. If you don't know both, please read about "Generics".

Comment: "[S] is for sub type" - where did you hear that?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Maybe I misunderstood from this block: `The list type in Scala is covariant. This means that for each pair of types S and T, if S is a subtype of T, then List[S] is a subtype of List[T].` (Book *Programming in Scala - 2010*)

Comment: Yeah, `S` and `T` are just what the author chose for that example. They could have used any other letters.

Comment: @bob, in mathematics `for each X` or `for every X` or `for all X` always means that `X` can be any element from some set defined by the context (set of types here), and `X` itself is an *arbitrary* identifier. It just happened that in this particular case the author took `T` and `S` (these are pretty common identifiers for types in programming languages with generics). Anyway, such limitations like "`T` is type" and "`S` is subtype" wouldn't be very natural. For example, of which type `S` is a subtype? If it is `T`, what do we do if we need more than two types? etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pick any name for generic types in Scala. So `A` here is just a name for the generic type. It could be `logging[T]` instead.

For more info you can refer to [Scala generic Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/generic-classes.html) and [Twitter Scala School](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html).

By the way, be aware that for making a function (or method) generic you have to put the generic type in brackets after the function name:

```
def myFunc[T](someStuff: T): Boolean = ....
```

or

```
def myFunc[T](someString: String): T = ....
```

Answer (score 4):

The A within the brackets is just an *arbitrary* type parameter placeholder.  It could be B, C whatever you want to use really.  Use of T doesn't specifically mean "type" and S doesn't specifically mean "subtype" - this is just happens to be a convention which is used within some libraries.

Quite often you might use a letter which acts as an aide memoire in terms of what a specific type parameter is there for, for example it's fairly common that M might be used for things like Monoids, Monads etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's just a cultural difference. Java community uses `T` while Scala community uses `A`, for the same reason, in the same situation.

Comment: Your point is sort of valid. I mean by reading Java standard library code and comparing it with Scala standard library code you'll see that `T` is all over the place in Java and `A` in Scala. But I guess from this one cannot conclude that this is a cultural difference. At least in Scala community (Take Play, Slick, Lift, ... as examples) you'll find different names for generic types. So I guess mentioning that this is just an arbitrary name for a generic type would be a better answer to this question.